# How to create an array object in it's own method

Tags: java, arrays

Hello I'm trying to do a little java course and it tells me to make a little program with a class(Point) that creates X, Y coordinates.
In a second part it asks me to make an array of an object of said class. My attempt was to create a method in it's own class to create it, I don't know if it's possible(or useful) and couldn't find a way to phrase it to google that gave me an answer I could understand.
Any way to improve the little thing I made is greatly appreciated.

```
import folderPointer.Point;

public class MainFile {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("\n\n\n");

    Point firstPoint = new Point();
    firstPoint.printPoint();
    System.out.println("\n\n");

    Point secondPoint[] = secondPoint.fillPArray();
    secondPoint = secondPoint.fillPArray();

}

}
```

edit* Missed my main

```
    Point secondPoint[] = secondPoint.fillPArray();
    secondPoint = secondPoint.fillPArray();
```

this part does not work.

```
package folderPointer;

import java.util.Random;

public class Point {
private int coordX;
private int coordY;

public Point() {
    coordX = 0;
    coordY = 0;
}

public Point(int coordX, int coordY) {
    this.coordX = coordX;
    this.coordY = coordY;
}

public Point(Point o) {
    this.coordX = o.coordX;
    this.coordY = o.coordY;
}

public void printPoint() {
    System.out.println("Coord X: " + this.coordX + ", CoordY:" + this.coordY);
}

public void modifyPoint(int coordX, int coordY) {
    this.coordX = coordX;
    this.coordY = coordY;
}

private Point[] createPArray() {
    Random ran = new Random();
    Point[] toReturn = new Point[ran.nextInt(19) + 1];
    return toReturn;
}

public Point[] fillPArray() {
    Point[] filledPoint = createPArray();
    Random randInt = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < filledPoint.length; i++) {
        filledPoint[i].coordX = randInt.nextInt(100);
        filledPoint[i].coordY = randInt.nextInt(100);
    }

    return filledPoint;

}

}
```

Comment: When you say "My attempt was to create a method in it's own class to create it", I think that you might be looking for the "Factory" pattern (just google for Factory Pattern).  It most certainly is useful, but only when programming with fairly advanced stuff (like dependency injection and unit testing.)  For now, I think you have a good way to make arrays of this class, and if it works, don't change it :)  I might suggest adding `static` modifier to the creation methods though, so you don't need to create a `Point` object in order to create the array.

Comment: I should've clarified, it does not work, I also missed some code somehow. Thanks for the tip I'll research that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you are trying to do is create an array of Point objects, I found that an easy way to do this is to make the "Point" class an inner class, initialize a Point array with:

```
Point[] pointArray = new Point[3];
```

I then made a few example points followed by a for loop to iterate through and print the results.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class PointHelp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Point[] pointArray = new Point[3];

        pointArray[0] = new Point(3, 4);
        pointArray[1] = new Point(4, 5);
        pointArray[2] = new Point(4,7);

        for(int i = 0; i < pointArray.length; i++){
            pointArray[i].printPoint();
        }
    }
}

class Point {
    private int coordX;
    private int coordY;

    public Point() {
        coordX = 0;
        coordY = 0;
    }

    public Point(int coordX, int coordY) {
        this.coordX = coordX;
        this.coordY = coordY;
    }

    public Point(Point o) {
        this.coordX = o.coordX;
        this.coordY = o.coordY;
    }

    public void printPoint() {
        System.out.println("Coord X: " + this.coordX + ", CoordY:" + this.coordY);
    }

    public void modifyPoint(int coordX, int coordY) {
        this.coordX = coordX;
        this.coordY = coordY;
    }

    private Point[] createPArray() {
        Random ran = new Random();
        Point[] toReturn = new Point[ran.nextInt(19) + 1];
        return toReturn;
    }

    public Point[] fillPArray() {
        Point[] filledPoint = createPArray();
        Random randInt = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < filledPoint.length; i++) {
            filledPoint[i].coordX = randInt.nextInt(100);
            filledPoint[i].coordY = randInt.nextInt(100);
        }
        return filledPoint;
    }

}
```

The output for this is as follows:

```
Coord X: 3, CoordY:4
Coord X: 4, CoordY:5
Coord X: 4, CoordY:7
```

Comment: I am sorry i forgot some code and clarification on my question. I think i understand, my problem it would be on main, if it is even "fixable". I'll try out the code you posted thank you.